# Conditional resolution in Unity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

The short version is, I would like to register possible implementations of an interface with Unity, but those implementations may not be available depending on the application configuration.

Specifically, these are two-factor implementations for ASP.NET Identity (email, SMS, etc).  Their parameters are set up in the web.config, and in certain environments they may not be available (for example, we can't send email from our dev laptops).

I would like to use ResolveAll to grab the ones that are available, and simply register the appropriate InjectionFactories, which, if they aren't available, return null.  However, this does in fact result in null items from the call to ResolveAll.

Basically, what I would like is the equivalent of the ability to, within the InjectionFactory `Func`, signal to Unity, "never mind; I can't actually resolve this, sorry; don't use me as a registration source".

Is this possible **without** :

1. splitting up the "can register" from the registration itself, so basically `if (CanRegisterEmailTwoFactor) container.Register<ITwoFactor>("Email", new InjectionFactory(CreateEmailTwoFactor))`
2. requiring all the `ResolveAll` calls to exclude nulls

Note also that there may also be two competing registrations (for example, internal SMTP vs SendGrid), and the default behavior would be to return just the last one registered, so I'd also like to avoid the second, unavailable one overwriting the first with null.

Comment: Can you use the [null object pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object)?

Comment: Not really; the items show up in a drop-down list to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Until a better answer comes along, what I did was replace RegisterType with RegisterInstance, as follows:

```
private static void ConditionalRegisterInstance<T>(IUnityContainer container, Func<IUnityContainer, T> factory)
{
            T toRegister = factory(container);
            if (toRegister != null)
                container.RegisterInstance<T>(toRegister);
}
```

This is acceptable with the two-factor providers because they can be reused.  As long as you don't mind creating and throwing away a "test instance", you could do the same with a factory too by using RegisterType after testing that the factory can  in fact create an item.